# Multi-State dependent Variable Encoding

Tags: encoding, data-science

I am a novice in this and am trying to get some knowledge over the pre-processing part I have the following query:

I am aware that if your dependent variable(y) has 2 states, then you might not need feature scaling on the dependent variable. But, in case of multi-state dependent variable like Customer_index(probable customer): no, yes, maybe , NA

If I use OnehotEncoder or LabelEncoder, i might get 0,1,2,3.
But, I believe when I try fitting up a model to this, the algorithm will assume this variables as ordinal/Weighted.

How can I handle this.

Some Useful artifact  I found:
https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02

Thanks for hep in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have some research on my questions above and I found once we apply encoding, **we anyhow must do scaling on our data** to apply biasness over the weights of the features and that is true for the multistate variable as well.

Let know your thoughts.